# Using JQuery to hide divs using a search box

Tags: jquery, html

My jQuery knowledge is limited and I have tried searching round the forum for an answer to my question but I can't quite get any suggest solutions to work and my inexperience is stopping me from seeing where my problems are occurring.

I have a page with some tiled cards, each containing more divs and other text elements. I would like to be able to search in a search box for any strings of text that could be anywhere in one of these cards and hide the rest of the cards which do not.

So far I have managed to get it working so that my search query is case insensitive and when it finds a match it will hide everything else within that card.

I feel like i'm close but I don't think I can quite make it there on my own.

```js
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
          var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
          });
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div class="boxes" id="myDIV">
  <div class="card HCAM" data-type="HCAM">
    <div class="card-image"></div>
    <div class="card-text">
      <span class="date">4 days ago</span>
      <h2>Post One</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, Ducimus, repudiandae
        temporibus omnis illum maxime quod deserunt eligendi dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-stats">
      <div class="stat">
        <div class="value">4<sup>m</sup></div>
        <div class="type">read</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stat border">
        <div class="value">5123</div>
        <div class="type">views</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stat">
        <div class="value">32</div>
        <div class="type">comments</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card L1700" data-type="L1700">
    <div class="card-image card2"></div>
    <div class="card-text card2">
      <span class="date">1 week ago</span>
      <h2>Post Two</h2>
      <p>Adipisicing elit. Ducimus, repudiandae corrupti amet temporibus omnis provident illum maxime quod. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-stats card2">
      <div class="stat">
        <div class="value">7<sup>m</sup></div>
        <div class="type">read</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stat border">
        <div class="value">7152</div>
        <div class="type">views</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stat">
        <div class="value">21</div>
        <div class="type">comments</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card L1500" data-type="L1500">
      <div class="card-image card3"></div>
      <div class="card-text card3">
        <span class="date">3 week ago</span>
        <h2>Post Three</h2>
        <p>Repudiandae corrupti amet temporibus omnis provident illum maxime. Ducimus, lorem ipsum dolor adipisicing elit</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-stats card3">
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="value">5<sup>m</sup></div>
          <div class="type">read</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat border">
          <div class="value">3021</div>
          <div class="type">views</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="value">15</div>
          <div class="type">comments</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it a very bad idea to search through each array of html divs and perform filter operations on it, you have to grab your content from your divs at page load and store it into a searchable array, then perform a search on that array instead

Comment: So if each card had a title, i.e. the h2, would it be better to just search for those? If so, would i just need to change "#myDIV *" for ".card h4" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give unique `class` to each card, so your selector will be more accurate (you can then easily select them like `$(".card")`). For this example I just selected all children of your div with id `myDIV`, iterate over them and hide/show them if they contain text from input search. Also a note that `filter` is used for filtering selected items, to run a function on each of the item it is preferred to use jQuery's command `each`.

Here is only slightly modified your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
          var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          
          $("#myDIV").children().each(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
          })
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div class="boxes" id="myDIV">
  <div class="card HCAM" data-type="HCAM">
    <div class="card-image"></div>
    <div class="card-text">
      <span class="date">4 days ago</span>
      <h2>Post One</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, Ducimus, repudiandae
        temporibus omnis illum maxime quod deserunt eligendi dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-stats">
      <div class="stat">
        <div class="value">4<sup>m</sup></div>
        <div class="type">read</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stat border">
        <div class="value">5123</div>
        <div class="type">views</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stat">
        <div class="value">32</div>
        <div class="type">comments</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card L1700" data-type="L1700">
    <div class="card-image card2"></div>
    <div class="card-text card2">
      <span class="date">1 week ago</span>
      <h2>Post Two</h2>
      <p>Adipisicing elit. Ducimus, repudiandae corrupti amet temporibus omnis provident illum maxime quod. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-stats card2">
      <div class="stat">
        <div class="value">7<sup>m</sup></div>
        <div class="type">read</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stat border">
        <div class="value">7152</div>
        <div class="type">views</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stat">
        <div class="value">21</div>
        <div class="type">comments</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card L1500" data-type="L1500">
      <div class="card-image card3"></div>
      <div class="card-text card3">
        <span class="date">3 week ago</span>
        <h2>Post Three</h2>
        <p>Repudiandae corrupti amet temporibus omnis provident illum maxime. Ducimus, lorem ipsum dolor adipisicing elit</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-stats card3">
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="value">5<sup>m</sup></div>
          <div class="type">read</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat border">
          <div class="value">3021</div>
          <div class="type">views</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="value">15</div>
          <div class="type">comments</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aha, I see where i was going wrong now. This makes much more sense. Thank you very much for your help!.